# getting event for phone lock when app is active in android

Tags: android, security, session, android-intent

I am developing an application which need security and login system.
I am using preferences to save session data.

If any user goes out of application, `onPause()` method is getting called and the app clears all its preferences data but this is where I am getting problem, when user's screen is locked then `onPause()` method is getting called and it clears all data.
I don't want to clear the data if users screen is locked.

**I used BroadcastReceiver to achieve this but I want a optimized solution**

```
 <receiver android:name=".SessionWakeBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**SessionWakeBroadcastReceiver code:**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SessionWakeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {


    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
       //Some Action
    }

    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {
           //Some Action
    }
}

}
```

in `onPause()` method , can I get that which intent is getting called if its phone lock then i will not perform data clearing.

any help will be appericiated

Thanks in advance

Comment: onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called

Comment: @Androidas what if user clicks on home button of android device it will not call the ondestroy menthod. but for other than phone lock I want to clear data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I get that which intent is getting called if its phone lock

You may be looking for the `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` actions.

But keep the following in mind:

> You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only
>   by explicitly registering for it with `Context.registerReceiver()`.

To check if the screen is locked, you could do something like this:

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if (km.isKeyguardLocked()) {
    // locked
} else {
    // not locked
}
```